# Android Jsoup parse RSS don't get value for link

Tags: java, android, parsing, rss, jsoup

I have simple RSS to parsing items to object:

```
    String html = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>\n" +
            "<rss version=\"2.0\" xmlns:atom=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\">\n" +
            "\n" +
            "<channel>\n" +
            "  <title>W3Schools Home Page</title>\n" +
            "  <link>http://www.w3schools.com</link>\n" +
            "  <description>Free web building tutorials</description>\n" +
            "  <item>\n" +
            "    <title>RSS Tutorial</title>\n" +
            "    <link>http://www.w3schools.com/rss</link>\n" +
            "    <description>New RSS tutorial on W3Schools</description>\n" +
            "    <image>\n" +
            "      <url>http://feed.mikle.com/images/rssicon.png</url>\n" +
            "    </image>\n" +
            "  </item>\n" +
            "  <item>\n" +
            "    <title>XML Tutorial</title>\n" +
            "    <link>http://www.w3schools.com/xml</link>\n" +
            "    <description>New XML tutorial on W3Schools</description>\n" +
            "    <image>\n" +
            "      <url>http://feed.mikle.com/images/rssicon.png</url>\n" +
            "    </image>\n" +
            "  </item>\n" +
            "</channel>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "</rss>";

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

    Log.d("string", doc.toString());

    for( Element item : doc.select("item") ) // Select all items
    {
        Log.d("title", item.select("title").first().text()); //OK
        Log.d("link", item.select("link").first().text()); //WTF?
        Log.d("image url", item.select("url").first().text());
    }
```

Why I can't get value link?

**Log.d("link", item.select("link").first().text()); //WTF?**

In console is: **D/link﹕ [ 01-21 23:07:26.710  2856: 2856 D/image url ]**

Where is problem?

How get URL in item foreach?

```
    <image>
       <url>http://feed.mikle.com/images/rssicon.png</url>
    </image>
```

Thanks

Comment: post the complete log.

Answer (score 0):

This is because in general html `<link>` tag wont have any body. In your case when you parse them, the link tag will become empty (`<link/>`) (You can observe that in the log `Log.d("string", doc.toString());`. Either you need to define it with some other tag (like `<p>` or `<a>`) or convert it to something like `<link href="www.w3school.com"/>`). In General link tags are used import the css files.